# Collection variable access in a request body postman

Tags: collections, automated-tests, postman

I have set collection variable in test script to my previous request. It has been set perfectly. Afterwards when I am trying to access it in body of my next request I am seeing the values on hoover, but it doesn't responds successfully.

Here is my script from 1st request:

```
console.log(jsonData.product.id);
pm.collectionVariables.set("option_id1",jsonData.product.variations[0].combination[0].option_id);
pm.collectionVariables.set("option_id2",jsonData.product.variations[0].combination[1].option_id);
pm.collectionVariables.set("option_v_id1",jsonData.product.variations[0].combination[0].option_value_id);
pm.collectionVariables.set("option_v_id2",jsonData.product.variations[0].combination[1].option_value_id);
pm.collectionVariables.set("sku_channel_id1",jsonData.product.variations[0].channel_data[0].sku_channel_id);
pm.collectionVariables.set("sku_channel_id2",jsonData.product.variations[0].channel_data[1].sku_channel_id);
```

Comment: What error did you got? pls add more details, like what you expect and what you actually got

Comment: I want to use "option_id" from a get request in next post request body! 
This is the test script! 

const jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
console.log(jsonData.product.id); 
pm.collectionVariables.set("option_id",jsonData.product.variations[0].combination[0].option_id); 

but after hitting the request, I get error like: 

Call to a member function update() on null .

Comment: Pls, attach the error image in question, I want to make sure the error you got is from your server, not your postman script.

Comment: hey @lucasnguyen17 thanks for answering, think I have done a mistake with my value datatype in request body, need to find out where! and yes, it is not a postman issue!